How can i do SetFont on itext7 Table Cell .Maui
i did not  that how i will write include of SetFont Method. My code as Below;
 Cell cellx1 = new Cell(i + 1, 1)
.SetMargin(10)
.SetFont(?????)
.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
.Add(new Paragraph(quoteP.Unitprice.ToString()));
 tableUrunler.AddCell(cellx1);


I Resolved as Below.Thank you.
.SetFont(iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_BOLD))


The Font you want to set need to be in bundle as embedded resource, Then you need to create a copy of the file in App data directory and pass the path to SetFont() method.
Step 1:

Add the font (.ttf file) to Resources/Fonts
Set the Build Action of the file to Embedded resource in it's Properties

Step 2:
Below is the sample code to access and set font to a iText Cell.
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using var fontStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNameSpace.Resources.Fonts.your-font.ttf");
string tempFontPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "your-font.ttf");
if(File.Exists(tempFontPath))
    File.Delete(tempFontPath);
        
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tempFontPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fontStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(tempFontPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
Cell cellx1 = new Cell(i + 1, 1)
.SetMargin(10)
.SetFont(font)
.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
.Add(new Paragraph(quoteP.Unitprice.ToString()));
 tableUrunler.AddCell(cellx1);


i resolved.i found it as below.
.SetFont(iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_BOLD))
